# Bootstrap modal on angular-ui makes scrollbar vanish

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui

I'm opening a modal in my directive code like that:

```
var modalInstance = $modal.open({
      templateUrl: "app/templates/modal-assign.html",
      controller: "assignModalController",
      resolve: {
        "call": function() {
          return $scope.call;
        }
      }
    });
```

But I have a validation on my assignModalController that I need to close my modal:
    AssignValidatorService.validateOpeningModal($scope).then(function(validation) {
      if (!validation.isValid) {
        $scope.handleCancel(validation.msg);
      }
      $rootScope.setBusyIndicator(false);
    }, function() {
      $rootScope.setBusyIndicator(false);
    });

and my handleCancel:

```
$scope.handleCancel = function(message) {
  $log.info(filename + " - handleCancel");
  $modalInstance.dismiss(message);
};
```

So, the modal is closing properly but the screen scrollbar disappeared.

After long time looking for answers, I figured out that bootstrap add a class modal-open in `<body>` tag. when this modal is close, bootstrap is suppose to remove that class from `<body>`. I inspected the DOM and I saw the modal-open class in `<body>`, I removed manually and the screen scrollbar reappeared.

I tried to remove on many ways that class by code in the handleCancel function, like this:

```
$scope.handleCancel = function(message) {
  $log.info(filename + " - handleCancel");
  angular.element(document).find("body").removeClass();
  $modalInstance.dismiss(message);
};
```

...but no success!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spent long hours I got my solution:

```
$scope.handleCancel = function(message) {
  $log.info(filename + " - handleCancel");
  $timeout(function(){
      $modalInstance.dismiss(message);
  }, 500);    
};
```

Probably the bootstrap process to add/remove the modal-open class was in the middle and I triggered to dismiss that modal, adding that class and doesn't remove. So I delay that dismiss action and everything is working fine right now

:D

Thanks!